how to refer to class members in a class template
I have 3 class templates below. My question is also in the code below.
#include <array>

template< typename T >
class XY
{
public:
       XY() = default;
       XY(T x, T y) { vec2 = { x,y }; }
       virtual ~XY() = default;
       auto X() const -> T { return vec2[0]; }
       auto Y() const -> T { return vec2[1]; }
private:
       std::array<T, 2> vec2;
};

template< typename T >
class xy
{
public:
       xy() = default;
       xy(T xx, T yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
       virtual ~xy() = default;
       T x, y;
};
template<typename T>
class coordinates {
public:
       T _pp;
       void printcoordinates() {
              // how can I refer to _pp.x or _pp.X() when it T can be either XY or xy
              _pp.x or _pp.X();
              _pp.y or _pp.Y();
       }
};


I have 3 class templates, XY, xy, and coordinates. Please see the code snippets above, in coordinates, how can refer to XY.X() and xy.x?

Which C++ standards are you using?

There are several ways to do this, but none of them are good. That is, I would not approve any of them in a code review. I would ask you to introduce a common way to refer to x and y coordinates in class XY and class xy, and use that common way in coordinates. For example, add X() and Y() methods to xy. Or perhaps just get rid of xy entirely.

fwiw, you do not need the trailing return when it can be deduced. I think it was only c++11 where it was needed, after that you can write auto X() const { return vec2[0]; }

@n.m.couldbeanAI what if those are library types? A recent example in RL gives me:  orange cube API and a library for interacting with flight radar - they literally have this capitalization difference - Google style vs. java style

@Swift-FridayPie: You solve that by a wrapper class for at least one of the two API's. A trivial namespace Foo { class xy : public Bar::xy { auto X() const { return this->x; } }; might  just be enough.

Technically speaking, you can do it with:
T _pp;

void printcoordinates() {
    if constexpr (requires { _pp.x; }) {
        // use _pp.x in here
    }
    else {
        // use _pp.X() in here
    }
}

That being said, what you're presumably trying to do is make it configurable whether _pp is storing an array or both members, and your approach to it is quite insane for multiple reasons:

You don't need polymorphic classes (i.e. a virtual destructor).
The base classes could just be simple aggregates. They don't need any constructor.
You probably want to inherit from T so that you don't need to go through _pp.
If you're not using inheritance, then the virtual destructor is totally useless.
Why not make both syntaxes possible? Store x and y members directly and then overload an operator[] that gives you access to either one, or alternatively, always store a std::array directly.
See also C++ access multiple members by array


One way to do this is to use a "traits" template instead:
template <typename T>
struct CoordinatesTraits;

template<typename T>
struct CoordinatesTraits<XY<T>>
{
  static T X(XY<T>& p) { return p.X(); }
};

template<typename T>
struct CoordinatesTraits<xy<T>>
{
  static T X(xy<T>& p) { return p.x; }
};

void printcoordinates() {
  CoordinatesTraits<T>::X(_pp);
}


@AlanBirtles it's scarier when real compiler agrees. I once had such case that MS compiler understood completely illegal template

A level of indirection helps. Write a trait that does nothing but retrieve the coordinates from any type and provide specializations for XY<T> and xy<T>. It has to be a class template, because there is no partial specialization for function templates. Instantiation of the trait and calling its method could be wrapped in a function template, instead i chose to provide a deduction guide which allows similar convenient call syntax. For illustration only the x part, y is the same:
template <typename T> struct get_coordinates;

template <typename T> struct get_coordinates<XY<T>> {
    const XY<T>& a;
    T get_X() { return a.X();}
};
template <typename T> struct get_coordinates<xy<T>> {
    const xy<T>& a;
    T get_X() { return a.x;}
};

template <typename T> get_coordinates(const T&) -> get_coordinates<T>;


template<typename T>
class coordinates {
public:
       T _pp;
       void printcoordinates() {
              std::cout << get_coordinates{_pp}.get_X();
       }
};

Live Demo
